# Possible for one resource to reference another?

Tags: serverless-framework

I have defined an S3 bucket in my `serverless.yml` file as follows:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    nameOfS3Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.stage}-name-of-s3-bucket
        AccessControl: Private
```

What I would like to do now is to reference the `arn` of the bucket in an IAM role which is also defined as a resource e.g.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    # s3 bucket definition removed for brevity
    iamRoleName:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: ${self:custom.stage}-iam-role-name
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: ${self:custom.stage}-iam-role-policy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action: "s3:PutObject"
                  Resource: *** Need the ARN of the s3 bucket here***
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) in cloudformation work fine inside `serverless.yml`, but *not* the yaml short form.

i.e. use `Fn::GetAtt` over `!GetAtt`

As long as you use the full syntax for yaml, it *should* work.

Try this (untested)

```
resources:
  Resources:
    nameOfS3Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.stage}-name-of-s3-bucket
        AccessControl: Private
    iamRoleName:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: ${self:custom.stage}-iam-role-name
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: ${self:custom.stage}-iam-role-policy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action: "s3:PutObject"
                  Resource: 
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [ nameOfS3Bucket, Arn ]
```